# How do i change the text on a button on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I need to make a button that changes the text inside it when the cursor is over it, and changes it back when the cursor leaves the box.
I have tried on VScode with "document.getElementById().innerHTML" but it just changes the text when the cursor goes on and it doesnt go back to the original text.

```css
button  {
    
    background-color: green;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    align-self: center;
}
body  {
    background-color: black;
}

h1  {
    color:green;
    text-align: center;
}

p   {
    color: chartreuse;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
}
button:hover{
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="website.css">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Web Page</h1>

<!-- Buttons -->
<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
Click to display Date and Time</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button"
onmouseover="this.innerHTML = Date()"
onmouseout="document.getElementById">What time is it</button>
<script>
    var x = "What time is it";
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't describe what you've tried. Show us what you've tried (post your code) so that we can identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** event and then can change innerHTML of the button.

```js
const btnEle = document.getElementById("btn");
btnEle.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  btnEle.innerHTML = "Save";
});

btnEle.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    btnEle.innerHTML = "Submit";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
              
        </title>
    </head>
      
    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="btn">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it is to have two `<span>`'s in my button.  The first `<span>` will contain the text you want to show by default.  The second `<span>` will contain the text you want to show on `hover`.  This span is hidden by default.

Then, you could add an event listener to your button.  On `mouseover`, hide the default text and show the `span` containing the hover text.  In a `mouseleave` event listener, just do the opposite.

HTML:

```
<button id="myid">
  <span class="default-text">Text 1</span>
  <span class="hover-text" style="display: none;">Text 2</span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
var button = document.getElementById('myid')

button.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

    this.querySelector('.hover-text').style.display="block";
    this.querySelector('.default-text').style.display="none";
});

button.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {

    this.querySelector('.default-text').style.display="block";
    this.querySelector('.hover-text').style.display="none";
});
```